# What is a belief as per the buddhism?

Tags: thoughtprocess

What I believe is what I look up to, everyday. Every belief originates me. Then am I a phenomena in itself?

Answer (score 2):

> What I believe is what I look up to, everyday.

What you believe in may just be your perception and not reality. Whatever you should be able to verify at the experiential level then you should look up to it. Since you know it from experience no external person needs to convince you of it.

> Every belief originates me.

Many thoughts gives arise to self notion which intern aversion or craving based on your evaluation. [[Tanhā Jālinī Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/31.15-Tanha-Jalini-S-a4.199-piya.pdf)] To be more precise you crave to the sensations based on your evaluation. This conditions your future.

> Then am I a phenomena in itself?

You are sum total of past conditioning including that of your past conditioning ue to yourself notion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Buddhism can be seen as a belief philosophy ,,  as you stated  all beliefs are from in you this doesn't mean that they are true !! That's why we need dharma ..and yes you can say one believes in dharma and Buddha ...you are a phenomena we all are !! Belief as a definition in Buddhism is little bit more complicated .. As statements like I believe are not the intended methods in this practice ...as the I am,..thing is seen as image and ego...and not permanent, if you were to say belief is imperninant then it would fit in Buddhist teachings and woud be unimportant and useless for the path. So it's complicated as most faith based religions that put faith and belief in a God are thriving all over the world .

Comment: I guess that the Buddhist equivalent of "belief" is "view": Buddhists have right or wrong "views".

Comment: Chris... We could use such terms but then it just seems like a word game ...how does one say I have right view without reference to some form of self notion ....

Comment: I think that what you call "self notion" might be called "identity view" or *sakkāya-diṭṭhi*, which it's better to abandon. See also topics like, [How is it wrong to believe that a self exists, or that it doesn't?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/15898/254)

Comment: Yes I know that self is a no no... But read the original owner of question !! And where it comes from ? Thanks