# Who am I? Who am I without past memory?

Tags: suffering

Who am I? Am I my memory? For example, I am hindu. I am engineer. I am Rajput.

Who am I without past memory? Am I my past memory? I am engineer. I am hindu.

Comment: Buddha says we are emptiness. "Indian", "engineer" are mental concepts. Parts of your memory could be damaged in an accident and temporarily or permanently erased. That would affect your knowledge of yourself and other things. You might lose your mental concepts concerning our identity. A similar thing has happened to one of my bosses, due to being overstressed. He had a mental breakdown and completely forgot all his knowledge of engineering.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Theravada Buddhism teaches that there isn't a good answer to this question, that it's not a good question to ask.

See this description of [Right View](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/index.html) especially where it talks about "a thicket of views".

Also that things you might consider "self" (e.g. body, feelings, etc.) are impermanent -- and also (impermanent) is every put-together thing -- and so it's better not to view those as "self" ("self-views" are unsatisfactory or lead to suffering).

See also [How is it wrong to believe that a self exists, or that it doesn't?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/15898/254)

Comment: It is Not your experience..

Comment: Please who are you

Comment: Is this not the question we are all asking, the answer to which is enlightenment?

Comment: [sabbe dhammā anattā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence#Description)

Answer (score 0):

The attachment, aversion, and ignorance is you. This ignorance could be gross (fetters) or subtle (anusaya)

Comment: Nice bro but you explain these word

Comment: The notion "I" is the ignorance and due to that, we have the grasping. (upadana)https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=35497

Answer (score 0):

I am nothing.
Live in this moment .
You are  nothing

Comment: [Right view](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/index.html): "And what is wrong view? 'There is nothing etc." I think that a statement like "I am nothing" is yet another self-view (like "I am everything", "I am eternal" etc.). I think the Buddha warned that literally any/every self-view (including "I am nothing") is unsatisfactory or leads to suffering.

Comment: Nice bro .... you are right