# Why do Buddhists believe in reincarnation?

Tags: reincarnation

What makes a person believe in the idea of reincarnation? It can’t be “because the books/teachers say so”, given the Buddhist ideology of “come and see by yourself”

Comment: There are several explanations of or justification for belief here: [Is rebirth a delusional belief?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3420/254)

Comment: Also, please be aware that "Why objects of class X do act Y" is a hard question to answer objectively as it requires understanding the motivation of an undefined number of objects belonging to X, when even their membership in X is hard to ascertain with confidence.

Comment: This is not enough for a full answer, but keep in mind that some people consider rebirth as a tentative working hypothesis, not necessarily getting attached to the idea, "having it there". If you ask me, it is always useful to acknowledge one's own ignorance and limits, and to humbly say "I don't know, yet, and maybe I'll never know". Kind regards!

Comment: Because it's considered a "safe bet" approach (see the "Safe Bet" sutta for more details: https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.060.than.html

Comment: Good question. I don't see a straight answer here as yet, which is odd. I'd guess we believe (where we don't know)  because rebirth is taught by so many accomplished masters, and because it makes sense of the world.

Comment: I've added a personal experience in my answer have a look.

Answer (score 6):

There is rebirth in Buddhism, for sure, but rebirth of what?

When we say "rebirth", we mean that something that we can peg onto as YOU, is born again after physical death. But what is YOU? The soul or self or the SAME consciousness that wanders on throughout this lifetime?

The Buddha taught that all phenomena is not self. The Buddha also taught that all conditioned and/or compounded things (including consciousness) is impermanent. It is not the SAME consciousness that wanders from childhood to old age. It changes. (See [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi))

So, in Buddhism, there is no rebirth of the self or consciousness.

In fact, if a person injures his brain or experiences dementia or amnesia or coma, then his personality, his memories and even his consciousness could be impaired or non-existent for the remainder of his physical life. In this case, even in his lifetime, we cannot guarantee that he is totally present at every moment. Then, what more for the next lifetime?

So, if a soul or self or consciousness is not reborn, then what is reborn?

There is definitely rebirth in Buddhism, but what is reborn?

1. Suffering. The continuity of suffering, regardless of physical death, is rebirth.
2. The continuity of conditioned processes when the condition for them to exist continues, is also rebirth. For e.g. karmic cause and effect, and its relationship to an individual's perceived continued existence in this lifetime. Also, the physical and mental processes of the [five aggregates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skandha), for e.g. the "stream" of consciousness ([MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/bodhi)) and the thought "I am the thinker" ([Snp 4.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.14.than.html)). The continuity of conditioned processes doesn't necessarily end at the death of the physical body.

The Theravada perspective is that at every moment there is death and rebirth. In between, we have the continuity of conditioned processes, that bridges every moment. With the continuity of conditioned processes, we have the continuity of suffering, so long as ignorance is present.

When ignorance is permanently ended, craving is permanently ended and suffering is permanently ended. This permanent ending of ignorance is referred to as enlightenment in Buddhism.

In [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/58/471), Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu wrote:

> ... the conclusion I make is that it's not that Buddhists believe in
>   rebirth, it's that we don't believe in death - the latter being merely
>   a concept referring to the change from one set of experiences to
>   another. True death only occurs either at every moment or at the
>   experience of nibbana.

Usually when people talk about rebirth, they imply that the SAME consciousness wanders on in this lifetime and onto the next lifetime. In the following quote from [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/30700/471), we read a nice explanation by Damith, of why this is not true.

> Stream of consciousness OR Continuity of consciousness means
>   individual consciousness which arises (*uppada*), exists (*titi*), ceases
>   (*bhanga*) rapidly as an effect of many causes. It's just a stream, not
>   a long lasting single one.
>
> Think of a stream of water. When you look at a single point in the
>   stream, you see many water droplets appear, exist, and disappear. Take
>   a single droplet out of it which passed by(*) that point. If you
>   consider the past, present, and future of that droplet, you'll see a
>   stream. In reality, it's not the same droplet nor another droplet you
>   see in the past, present, and future. Stream of consciousness is
>   analogous to this example. Please try to understand it in that way.
>
> (*) Note: "passed by" - This phrasal verb can be only used when we
>   talk in conventional truth. The reader may think that rūpa
>   (form/matter) can move in space which is not a true in ultimate
>   reality. Neither any nāma (name) nor rūpa can move. What happens is
>   the arose rūpa existed and ceased then and there. After that new rūpa
>   arise nearby. This is called "Deshāntarotpatti".

I'm not saying that there is no YOU (self) at all. There is a YOU, but it's not a permanent YOU. It's changing from moment to moment, depending on conditions, and compounded by different mental and physical processes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was confused for years - now I think I begin to understand :-D

Answer (score 2):

Real Buddhists don't believe in things. Because buddhism or its concepts are not to believe as buddhism is not a religion. Followers can experiment and make sure the concepts / ideology are true. Ofcourse there are things which only buddha can see eg: universe, to know some one is arhanth or not, etc.

So real buddhist don't believe in reincarnation, but it doesn't mean Buddhism does't accept reincarnation.  It's proven to them with `ñāṇa`. If you want to experience it you can meditate and develop your mind to see your previous lives. Or else, theoretically you can understand it by learning [Pratītyasamutpāda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da).

To answer the question of Why do Buddhist believe in reincarnation: It's because it's true. That's the truth of the world. Everything happens in according to the Pratītyasamutpāda, and everything has a cause. We see the results. Buddhist understand the cause and stop the cause and as a result they attain Nivana.

**Update**:

Personal experience of a women can be found [in this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuLzB-Xt980&list=PLCwAkX1DFpzLkZu1nAmslO04HAaPgaWRx&index=17&t=0s). Watch from 1:40 minute from there it's English. At 14th mins she explains about previous life story.

Comment: Who ever down vote this, could you please explain the reason. Just down voting an answer doesn't make any sense for the community.

Comment: I think there's a user on this site who doesn't "believe in reincarnation" (i.e. believe that reincarnation is "true"), and who will tend to downvote any answer which says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I gather it isn't strictly a binary decision.

It's tempting to say, "if it isn't A then it must be B", but maybe A and B are both true, or maybe neither are.

There are some problems with *not* believing:

- The books/teachers say so
- It would seem to be "annihilationism" -- which the suttas explicitly identify as a wrong view
- It may be associated with immoral behaviour (e.g. of the "nothing matters" or "no future" variety)

There may be *some* problems *with* believing, too:

- E.g. that it's a "mundane" doctrine rather than super-mundane
- It may be associated with self-views
- It has historically lead to questions like, "if it's not the 'self' that's incarnated, then what *is*, and via what medium?" -- so metaphysical (and not necessarily useful or practical) questions

I once thought that [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/58/254) was one of the clearer answers I had read -- and fairly easy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Buddha rejected both eternalism and nihilism. He taught dependent origination. What Buddhism teaches is the Dependent Origination based on birth.
Re-birth cause suffering hence it is an important part of Four Noble Truth is based on the re-birth idea.

Answer (score 0):

People who believe in "Reincarnation" are sort of missing the point of Buddhism.  It is all about living your best life now.  If you start worrying about what happens in the next life then you are going to be living this life for all the wrong reasons.  Especially as you will never know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Buddhists personally believe but I know what the sammasambuddha Gautama believed.

He did not believe in the popular media portrayal of reincarnation as in "rebirth only as a human over and over again".

He instead posits five destinations (nibbana is not included):

> "Sariputta, there are these five destinations. What are the five?
>   Hell, the animal realm, the realm of ghosts, human beings and devas"
>   (MN 12)

He had actually debunked the popular media portrayal of reincarnation in the Pansu suttas stating that the vast majority of humans after death go to hell, the animal realm, or the realm of ghosts after death instead of being reborn as a human or deva.

Birth as a human is extremely rare and usually more pleasant than other existences.

The majority of humans will waste their existence and go to hell, the animal realm, or the realm of ghosts after death including many people perceived as good people.

I personally believe in the Buddhist concept of rebirth because it makes the most sense to me out of any other explanations of the afterlife and also somewhat matches into personal observations.

Gautama the sammasambuddha was the greatest teacher ever in history in my opinion with over 10,000 suttas, many debates and detailed explanations.

But Right View is part of the Eightfold Path and viewed as the forerunner:

> "And what is the right view with effluents, siding with merit,
>   resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
>   what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
>   There is this world & the next world. There is mother & father. There
>   are spontaneously reborn beings; there are contemplatives & brahmans
>   who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the
>   next after having directly known & realized it for themselves.' This
>   is the right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
>   acquisitions." (MN 117)

I don't blame people for doubting during this time-period seems like there aren't any real arahants skilled interacting with people that exist.

If uncertain then practice metta (loving-kindness):

> “Bhikkhus, whatever grounds there are for making merit productive of a
>   future birth, all these do not equal a sixteenth part of the
>   mind-release of loving-kindness. The mind-release of loving-kindness
>   surpasses them and shines forth, bright and brilliant." (Iti 27)

But the real purpose of Buddhism is to achieve arahantship or enlightnment here and now, to finally be able to enjoy this moment.

Answer (score -1):

A person may believe in the idea of reincarnation for many reasons, such as:

1. They lust for life & they fear death. The suttas say, for the unenlightened, "death is suffering".
2. They are unable to take refuge in the Dhamma as taught by the Buddha, namely, the Dhamma is “come and see by yourself” ("sanditthiko akaliko ehipassiko opanayiko paccattam vedittabbo vinnuhiti").
3. They misinterpret Dependent Origination and the Noble Truths according to their defiled lusts, as explained in [SN 46.55](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn46/sn46.055.wlsh.html) . It does matter how many times Dependent Origination and the Noble Truths are explained to them with clear references from the scriptures, their lust for reincarnation & rejection of impermanence cannot be abated.
4. Due to the above realities, there are (later) teachings placed into the Buddhist scriptures that literally teach reincarnation for those people who are *unable to abandon self-view or upadhi (MN 117)*. These teachings raise donations for monks & are supposed to *nurture morality (MN 117)*. However, many people are so sinful they start to claim it is not "me" that is reincarnated; thus they negate all moral responsibility for their own deeds. Heretically, they start to teach the opposite of what the Buddha taught, which was "*beings are the heirs to their actions*".
5. In summary, Buddhism is something that has became degenerate; that narcissists that promote sexual promiscuity preach a Protestant-style "reincarnation without morality". Such is their lust for sensuality. There is a sutta that clearly states those that lust for sensuality fear death.
6. The suttas (eg MN 26; [Dhp 174](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.13.budd.html)) say the majority of people are unable to realise the Truth.
7. In conclusion, reincarnation is believed by "*thick*" people the Buddha called "*puthujjana*".

Answer (score -1):

St. Augustine said, "Faith is to believe what we do not see, and the reward of this faith is to see what we believe." This is the reason why Right View is the first path of the Eightfold Path: to have an idea of what reality is and to believe in it is helpful for attaining direct knowledge of it. Sages have the ability to remember their past lives: this is one of the psychic abilities. While it is true that you must gain insight for yourself, there is no reason to disbelieve the teachings of those who have gone beyond birth and death.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to answer with the help of philosopher Kapil. Kapila  denied  the  theory  that  there  was  a  being  who  created  the  universe. In  his  view  a  created  thing  really  exists  beforehand  in  its  cause  just  as  the clay  serves  to  form  a  pot,  or  the  threads  go  to  form  a  piece  of  cloth. 10.  This  is  the  first  ground  on  which  Kapila  rejected  the  theory  that  the universe  was  created  by  a  being. 11.  But  there  are  other  grounds  which  he  advanced  in  support  of  his  point of  view. 12.  The  non-existent  cannot  be  the  subject  of  an  activity  :  There  is  no  new creation.  The  product  is  really  nothing  else  than  the  material  of,  which  it  is composed  :  the  product  exists  before  its  coming  into  being  in  the  shape  of  its material  of  which  it  is  composed.  Only  a  definite  product  can  be  produced from  such  material  ;  and  only  a  specific  material  can  yield  a  specific  result. 13.  What  then  is  the  source  of  the  empirical  universe  ? 14.  Kapila  said  the  empirical  universe  consists  of  things  evolved  (Vyakta) and  things  that  are  not  evolved  (Avyakta). 15.  Individual  things  (Vyakta  Vastu)  cannot    be  the  source  of  unevolved things  (Avyakta  Vastu). 16.  Individual  things  are  all  limited  in  magnitude  and  this  is  incompatible with  the  nature  of  the  source  of  the  universe. 17.  All  individual  things  are  analogous,  one  to  another  and,  therefore,  no one  can  be  regarded  as  the  final  source  of  the  other.  Moreover,  as  they  all come  into  being  from  a  source,  they  cannot  constitute  that  source. Further,  argued  Kapila,  an  effect  must  differ  from  its  cause,  though  it must  consist  of  the  cause.  That  being  so,  the  universe  cannot  itself  be  the final  cause.  It  must  be  the  product  of  some  ultimate  cause. 19.  When  asked  why  the  unevolved  cannot  be  perceived,  why  does  it  not show  movement  which  would  make  it  perceivable,  Kapila  replied  : 20.  "  It  may  be  due  to  various  causes.  It  may  be  that  its  fine  nature  makes,  it imperceptible,  just  as  other  things  of  whose  existence  there  is  no  doubt, cannot  be  perceived  ;  or  because  of  their  too  great  a  distance  or  proximity  ; or  through  the  intervention  of  a  third  object,  or  through  admixture  with similar  matter  ;  or  through  the  presence  of  some  more  powerful  sensation, or  the  blindness  or  other  defect  of  the  senses  or  the  mind  of  the  observer." 21.  When  asked  :  "What  then  is  the  source  of  the  universe  ?  What  makes  the difference  between  the  evolved  and  unevolved  part  of  the  universe  ? 22.  Kapila's  reply  was:    'Things  that  have  evolved  have  a  cause  and  the things  that  have  not  evolved  have  also  a  cause.  But  the  source  of  both  is uncaused  and  independent.' 23.  "  The  things  that  have  evolved  are  many  in  number  and  limited  in  space and  name.  The  source  is  one,  eternal  and  all-pervasive.  The  things  evolved have  activities  and  parts  :  the  source  is  imminent  in  all,  but  has  neither activities  nor  parts." 24.  Kapila  argued  that  the  process  of  develop-ment  of  the  unevolved  is through  the  activities  of  three  constituents  of  which  it  is  made  up,  Sattva, Rajas  and  Tamas.  These  are  called  three  Gunas. 25.  The  first  of  the  constituents,  or  factors,  corresponds  to  what  we  call  as light  in  nature,  which  reveals,  which  causes  pleasure  to  men  ;  the  second  is that  impels  and  moves,  what  produces  activity  ;  the  third  is  what  is  heavy and  puts  under  restraint,  what  produces  the  state  of  indifference  or inactivity. 26.  The  three  constituents  act  essentially  in  close  relation,  they  overpower and  support  one  another  and  intermingle  with  one  another.  They  are  like the  constituents  of  a  lamp,  the  flame,  the  oil  and  wick. 27.  When  the  three  Gunas  are  in  perfect  balance,  none  overpowering  the other,  the  universe  appears  static  (Achetan)  and  ceases  to  evolve. When  the  three  Gunas  are  not  in  balance,  one  overpowers  the  other,  the universe  becomes  dynamic  (sachetan)  and  evolution  begins. 29.  Asked  why  the  Gunas  become  unbalanced,  the  answer  which  Kapila gave  was  this  disturbance  in  the  balance  of  the  three  Gunas  was  due  to  the presence  of  Dukha  (suffering). 30.  Such  were  the  tenets  of  Kapila's  philosophy. 31.  Of  all  the  philosophers  the  Buddha  was  greatly  impressed  by  the doctrines  of  Kapila. 32.  He  was  the  only  philosopher  whose  teachings  appeared  to  the  Buddha  to be  based  on  logic  and  facts. 33.  But  he  did  not  accept  everything  which  Kapila  taught.  Only  three  things did  the  Buddha  accept  from  Kapila. 34.  He  accepted  that  reality  must  rest  on  proof.  Thinking  must  be  based  on rationalism. 35.  He  accepted  that  there  was  no  logical  or  factual  basis  for  the presumption  that  God  exists  or  that  he  created  the  universe. 36.  He  accepted  that  there  was  Dukha  (suffering)  in  the  world. 37.  The  rest  of  Kapila's  teachings  he  just  bypassed  as  being  irrelevant  for  his purpose. Buddha do believe in rebirth that's why he found the way to unbinding. Unbinding of what ? Unbinding of Vyakta from Avyakta and merging to their relative source. Then there is nothing you can call as self. That's Nirvana.

Comment: I'm puzzled about why you post e.g. the doctrine of Kapila and Adisankara as being "Buddhist" doctrine. Is it because, are they referenced in _The Buddha and His Dhamma_, by Dr. B. R. Ambedkar, i.e. do people consider these doctrines/philosophers to be a part of [Navayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navayana)?

Comment: When path is lost there is arise need to show it again. For that you have to go back to earliest findings. One needs the references of past philosophies. Buddha on way to his journey always listen to what others have to say like Kapila, Arada and Udraka. Path of relieving of suffering is univarsal, it's not sectarian. In buddhism there were many sects like Mahayana, Hinyana, sarvastivadin, sanghika, ajivikas. Which sect you belong and called Buddhism. I am not interested in sects but truth.